# How to prevent user who does not have approval rights to click redeploy if approved task fail in release?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In a release pipeline, we have a post deployment approval in a stage 1 task which triggers the  stage 2 task. In the Approval Policies, we have checked the box: "The user requesting a release or deployment should not approve it". Once the stage 1 task has been approved by someone other than the user requesting the release, the stage 2 task is deployed and executes. However, if the stage 2 task fails, how can we prevent the user requesting a release or deployment from clicking the redeploy button? Currently, the redeploy button can be clicked by anyone.

Comment: Hi greenjackal - good question!

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/approvals?view=azure-devops#post-deployment-approvals

Add a post deployment approval.

[image]